# Is a transfer homomorphism surjective?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be finite group with minimal number of generators$d$, and all his proper subgroups have at most $d-1$ as minimal number of generators.
Fix a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.
For all subgroups $H$ of $G$ satisfying $[HN,N] \subseteq N^2$; consider the transfer homomorphism $HN \rightarrow H/H^2$.
Is it surjective?

Comment: What do $N^2$ and $H^2$ mean?

Comment: $N^2$ is the subgroup generated by all the squares of $N$, the same thing for $H^2$.

Comment: Suppose we let $G = C_2 \times C_2$ be a Klein $4$-group and $H$ and $N$ distinct subgroups of order $2$. Is that not a counterexample? The transfer map is $g \mapsto g^2$, so the image is trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you very much professor, it is indeed a counterexample.